# PyCharm wrong working directory at runtime

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm writing a simple flask application, using a form to upload an image, but since the upload worked but i couldn't find the image in the folder it was supposed to be... I printed `os.getcwd()`, finding out that it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.0\jre\jre\bin`.
Yet, if I issue the same command in the IDE console, i get the right one:

```
C:\\Users\\<username>\\PycharmProjects\\<projectname>'
```

my init.py

```
db = database.Database()
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static", static_folder="static")
print(app.static_folder)
#app.debug = True
app.config.from_object('config')
#toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
#app.config['DEBUG_TB_PROFILER_ENABLED'] = True
lm = LoginManager()
lm.login_view = 'login'
lm.anonymous_user = Anonymous
lm.init_app(app)
```

the upload part in my app.py

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    item['name'] = form.name.data
    item['order'] = form.order.data
    item['description'] = form.description.data
    item['category'] = form.categories.data
    item['tags'] = form.tags.data
    if form.image.data:
        image_name = mytools.secure_filename(form.image.data.filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(folder, image_name)
        image_data = Image.open(form.image.data)
        image_data.save(filepath.encode('utf-8'))
        mytools.resize_photo(filepath)
        item['image'] = image_name
    db.db.products.save(item)
```

Comment: You should assign a folder to store uploads and use full name. Also this folder should be readable and writable by the user under which flask runs (it's user "nobody" by default). And if flask runs as a different user, it cannot write to your personal space.

Comment: I used this very same setup on another project and it worked, so I don't think it's a permission issue... Also it is saving uploads correctly, but since I'm using a relative path they are being stored in the "wrong" path. I'll use an absolute path, but still don't get why it doesn't work as expected...